# how to change the position of app bar?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

in windows phone 8 when i uncomment the following code the application bar appears in the bottom of the page i need to make it appears at the top of the page

```
phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
        <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True" >
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button1.png" Text="Button 1"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button2.png" Text="Button 2"/>
        </shell:ApplicationBar>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ApplicationBar always appears on the bottom. If you need something like the ApplicationBar positioned on top, you need to write this yourself.

Comment: Additionally one should say, that on the Windows Phone plattform the ApplicationBar has to be on the bottom. The user expacts that and it is part of the design language. If even possible please adopt that in your app and don't try to let it look like an Android or iOS app.